# Behavior of the asterisk in field required under Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have a simple question but I have no found response about it.. do you know if it is possible to add the required asterisk in the field at the beginning of the label instead of the end in a Sencha Touch app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the following to your sass:

```
.x-field-required .x-form-label {
  &::after {
    content: '';
  }
  &::before {
    content: "*";
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works correctly, but in my case only I show asterisk when the field is required... with this code is shown always.

Comment: Ups. - thought you could see how this works. :) I edited my post, so that it should work now.